# Not sure why submitting the signup form is not displaying the php with test

Tags: javascript, php, forms

When I click submit with the info, it just reloads the page instead of showing Test. When I remove the JavaScript, it works and it shows the message. I don't know what's wrong with it?

Also when I remove the else statement in php, it shows a blank site so it seems to work but it's not picking up the submit being clicked when using JavaScript to submit it

My JS

```
const form = document.querySelector('.login-signup');
form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
 
    event.preventDefault(); 

    validateInputs();

    const successFields = form.querySelectorAll(".success");
    if (successFields.length === 2) {
        document.myForm.submit();
    }  
});
```

my php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["submit2"])) {
    echo "Test!";
} else {
    header("location: ../signup.php");
}
```

I want it to display Test when the form submits

Comment: Looks like you are struck in infinite loop while submitting the form. You must use ajax or some break logic to submit the form.

Comment: Add a console.log after the ``if (successFields.length === 2`` block. it's possible the statement fails, but since you have nothing after the if statement the system does not know what to do next. 

Also, is v``alidateInputs()`` something that you wrote?

Comment: `if (isset($_POST["submit2"]))` - are you trying to check for the submit button of the form here? Submitting a form via JavaScript, does not include the submit button in the parameter set.

Comment: I think you might be right on that CBroe, I was trying to check if the button named "submit2" was being clicked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I figured it out a while ago. It's because the submit type and name had the same name so it messed up my code. I used if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') which fixed it